# How does the Java String class work internally?

Tags: java, string, immutability

In my programming class we are creating a class that resembles the Java String class. Right now, we create a new object like this :

```
MyString string = new MyString("Hello World");
```

Which is fine and all, but in Java you can create a new String object like this:

```
String string = "Hello World";
```

Is there someway to emulate that?  Isn't this what people call immutable, where you can change the object after you create it, and add on to the object?

Edit:
Apparently I need to go back to English class. The 'Im' in immutable means 'not'... Oops, I meant mutable.

Comment: This way of initialization you cannot do for your own class.

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with immutability. That is a `String` literal which is processed by the Java compiler. It's part of the language specification. You would have to implement your own compiler if you wanted similar behavior.

Comment: There's no way to add this functionality?

Comment: [You would have to implement your own compiler if you wanted similar behavior.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460819/how-does-the-java-string-class-work-internally#comment32386302_21460819)

Comment: @opiop65 Not without editing the Java compiler or making your own compiler (i.e. doing something ridiculously hard and completely unnecessary).

Comment: No, there's no operator overload in java.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Haha, I got really confused following your link for awhile.  I was like, "Why won't it take me to the post he's linking to?"  Well played.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being "immutable" is actually the opposite of what you describe; it means the object *cannot* be changed after creation or added to.

Regardless, this has nothing to do with immutability.  There is no way to emulate that construction for your own classes.  String literals are part of the bare bones specification of the language.  Just like we have no operator overloading in Java (and thus have no way to make the compiler interpret `+` the way we'd like it to), we have no way to make the compiler understand a different set of literals.  They just are what they are.

I'm sure there is some brilliant way to modify the JVM and create your own compiler to do what you want, but then you're not really using Java anymore.

You can read more about literals in the [JLS 3.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10), or the official Oracle tutorials ([this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) for `String`s, [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for actual primitive types).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, string literals *are* instances of the `String` class. So in your second example, no conversion takes place. It has nothing to do with immutability (but you would run into problems if Strings were mutable).

EDIT: To see how the `String` class works internally, have a look at its [source](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) (OpenJDK).

Answer (score 0):

Another example

```
Integer Int = 5;
```

OR

```
Integer Int = new Integer (5);
```

Both works fine.

Also the below works as well.

```
 Integer Int;
 int i = 5;
 Int = i ;
```

I think this is special behavior for few Types only. Possibly be the equal operator is overloaded.

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator overloading.  It's called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).  And it works between all primitive types and their respective wrapper classes.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff.  See - http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1299048  "It is true that Java does not allow operator overloading. It is also true that an exception was made for String, although this is out of the control of developers as it is a built in feature of Java. "  So I agree that operator overloading is not correct word here.  I presume String  literal conversion or primitive to wrapper casting all are done internally by either the compiler or the runtime. There is no way for the Developer to emulate this behavor.